# how to add a xpi extension to a firefox browser from TFS with selenium java

Tags: firefox, selenium, tfs, firefox-addon

how I can add xpi extension to my browser from TFS server instead of my local drive?
I use addfile( C:/../) to add extension to the firefox profile from my mapped drive of tfs and it works, But the thing is the ectension is on the server and I want everyone to be able to run this test and add the extension file to their browsers from the server, what address I shpould put for the add file command?

Comment: My suggestion would be it's better to host/save the XPI file, internally on site which is easily accessible for everyone (which has NO authentication) as connecting to TFS itself will need authentication to be done and integrating it in scripts will be a pain.

Answer (score 2):

You can [use the AddonManager to install new add-ons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Manager#Installing_new_add-ons) this way:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm");

AddonManager.getInstallForURL("http://www.foo.com/test.xpi", function(aInstall) {
  // aInstall is an instance of AddonInstall
  aInstall.install();
}, "application/x-xpinstall");
```